# Coolpad 8297l-100 E: failed to verify whole-file signature when updating through rom file?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, root-access

i am using Coolpad 8297l-100 E now it is getting very slow,not showing gallary i formatted it through settings but issues all remained for that i decided to root using original rome file but it gives error.

Please help me soon to resolve this issue

Comment: Why do you want to root? Of the problem is with the ROM, a simple flashing​ should solve the problem.  Besides, you can't root using ''original rom''! There are many rooting methods

Comment: @esQmo_ i tried to flash using rom but is shows whole file signature varifyctaion failed

Comment: How did you proceed?

Comment: @esQmo_ i downloaded stock rom file from official site then i put it in phone memory and rename it as update.zip then i go recover menu and select the file from sd card when boot

Comment: May be it wasn't a recovery flashable zip.

Comment: You need acm computer to flash this device

Comment: is there is another way?

Comment: Sure. I'll post an answer explaining how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If flashing through recovery results in an error, it's probably because the file you are trying to flash is not intended to be flashed via recovery.

In this case, you have to flash using a computer instead.

Coolpad devices need a software called [YGDP](https://androidmtk.com/download-ygdp-tool) which will do the job for you.

You also need a CPB firmware.

Instructions on how to use the software can be found [here](https://androidmtk.com/flash-cpb-firmware-using-ygdp-tool)

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will surly upvot your answer when i able to upvotw

Comment: I'm glad I helped solve your problem